# Restoring job-queue between telegram-bot restarts

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've built a small telegram bot using python-telegram-bot.

When a conversation is started,I add a periodical job to the job queue and then message back to the user every X minutes.

Problem is when my bot goes offline (maintenance, failures, etc), the jobqueue is lost and clients do not receive updates anymore unless they send `/start` again

I could maybe store all chat_ids in a persistent queue and restore them at startup but how do I send a message without responding to an update ?

Answer (score 0):

you have lots of options. at first you need to store all chat_ids. you can do it in database or simple text file.
then you need a trigger in order to start sending messages. I'm not familiar with your technology but i just create simple service in order to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

In your particular case, it is faster to implement a straightforward solution: store chat_id in the file or some other persistence layer and then recreate all the jobs during the bot starting phase.

It has pitfalls though. To name a few:

1. You should duplicate the logic of job creation
2. You should store not only chat_id, but everything else that is needed to create a job (timing, personalization, etc)
3. The restored jobs may still have irrelevant schedules, e.g. it was daily in the morning, but the bot restarted in the evening, so now it is daily in the evening.

I have a universal solution that allows to use any scheduled jobs (run_repeating, run_daily, etc), created from any function.
You can find the example [here](https://github.com/dikirilov/ptb-job-persistence-stackoverflow/tree/main).

---

Here is the example of how it could be used in your bot:

```
import random
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes
import sys
from apscheduler.events import EVENT_JOB_REMOVED, EVENT_JOB_ADDED, JobEvent
from loguru import logger
from job_serialization import save_jobs_to_file, restore_jobs_from_file
import os

TOKEN = "<paste your token here>"
FILENAME = "<paste path+filename>"
job_queue = None
logger.remove()
logger.add(sys.stdout, level="DEBUG", format="<green>{time}</green> | <blue>{module}</blue> | <lvl>{level}</lvl> | {message}", serialize=False)


async def tick(context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=context.job.chat_id,
        text=f"Tick from {context.job.name}"
    )


async def add_ticker(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    logger.info(f"Starting ticking")
    num = len(context.job_queue.jobs())
    seconds = random.randint(5, 15)
    msg = f"Scheduling job-{num} every {seconds} seconds"
    logger.info(msg)
    context.job_queue.run_repeating(tick, seconds, chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                                    name=f"job-{num}")
    await context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
        text=msg,
    )


async def remove_ticker(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    logger.info(f"Stopping ticking")
    job = context.job_queue.jobs()[-1]
    name = job.name
    job.schedule_removal()
    msg = f"Removed {name}"
    logger.info(msg)
    await context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
        text=msg,
    )


def scheduler_event_catcher(event: JobEvent):
    logger.debug(f"Scheduler event: {event}, job id: {event.job_id}, jobstore name: {event.jobstore}, current job queue: {job_queue}")
    if job_queue:
        logger.info(f"job queue is defined, saving jobs to {FILENAME}")
        save_jobs_to_file(job_queue, FILENAME)
    else:
        logger.warning(f"job queue is not defined")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if TOKEN is None:
        logger.error(f"No token configured for bot")
        return
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()
    app.job_queue.scheduler.add_listener(scheduler_event_catcher, EVENT_JOB_REMOVED | EVENT_JOB_ADDED)
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("add_ticker", add_ticker))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("remove_ticker", remove_ticker))
    logger.info('Handlers added')
    global job_queue
    job_queue = app.job_queue
    restore_jobs_from_file(job_queue, FILENAME)

    logger.info('Starting polling...')
    app.run_polling()
```

I'm using [loguru](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) for logging purposes, please adjust it in case you are using a standard logging library or something else.

Bot relies on functions *save_jobs_to_file* and *restore_jobs_from_file* that are coming from a separate [module](https://github.com/dikirilov/ptb-job-persistence-stackoverflow/blob/main/job_serialization.py). The module encompasses internal logic to handle serialization/deserialization and working with files:

```
from loguru import logger
import pickle
import sys
import os
from apscheduler.util import ref_to_obj, obj_to_ref
from apscheduler.job import Job
from telegram.ext import JobQueue as PTBJobQueue, Job as PTBJob


logger.remove()
logger.add(sys.stdout, level="TRACE", format="<green>{time}</green> | <blue>{module}</blue> | <lvl>{level}</lvl> | {message}",
           serialize=False)


def restore_state(job_queue: PTBJobQueue, serialized_job: dict):
    if serialized_job["type"] != "PTB job":
        logger.warning(f"Unsupported job type: {serialized_job['type']}")
        return
    if serialized_job["version"] != 1:
        logger.warning(f"Unsupported job version: {serialized_job['version']}")
        return
    logger.debug(f"Restoring PTB job {serialized_job['name']}")
    callback = ref_to_obj(serialized_job["callback"])
    j = job_queue.run_custom(callback, data=serialized_job["data"], name=serialized_job["name"],
                             chat_id=serialized_job["chat_id"], user_id=serialized_job["user_id"], job_kwargs={})
    job_id = j.job.id
    j.job.__setstate__(serialized_job["state"])
    j.job.id = job_id
    j.job.func = job_queue.job_callback
    j.job.args = (job_queue, j)
    logger.debug(f"Restored PTB job {serialized_job['name']} with {j.job.trigger}")


def retrieve_state(job: Job):
    logger.trace(f"Data for {job.id=} is to be retrieved")
    state = job.__getstate__()
    ptb_job: PTBJob = job.args[1]
    # eliminate extra references that might be restored from other sources
    state['args'] = None
    serializable = {
        "type": "PTB job",
        "version": 1,
        "PTB_deleted": False,
        "callback": obj_to_ref(ptb_job.callback),
        "data": ptb_job.data,
        "name": ptb_job.name,
        "removed": ptb_job.removed,
        "enabled": ptb_job.enabled,
        "chat_id": ptb_job.chat_id,
        "user_id": ptb_job.user_id,
        "state": state
    }
    logger.trace(f"{state=}")
    return serializable


def save_jobs_to_file(job_queue: PTBJobQueue, filename: str) -> bool:
    serialized = [retrieve_state(job.job) for job in job_queue.jobs()]
    logger.debug(f"Saving {len(serialized)} jobs to file {filename}")
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        try:
            pickle.dump(serialized, f)
            logger.debug(f"Saved {len(serialized)} jobs to file {filename}")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Failed to save jobs to {filename}: {e}")
    return True


def restore_jobs_from_file(job_queue: PTBJobQueue, filename: str) -> bool:
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        logger.warning(f"File {filename} does not exist")
        return None
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        unpickler = pickle.Unpickler(f)
        try:
            data = unpickler.load()
            logger.info(f"Read {len(data)} jobs from {filename}")
        except EOFError:
            data = None
            logger.info(f"{filename} is empty")
    if not data:
        logger.warning(f"Nothing to restore.")
        return False
    for job in data:
        restore_state(job_queue, job)
    return True
```

---

**The longer and more comprehensive answer**

The question is rather old, but it is still relevant from my perspective. At least, I cannot find any other similar query or answer to it.

I was around the same issue recently. Whilst your particular example is not so complex, I was looking for a universal solution that would let me use any type of scheduling (run_repeating, run_daily, etc). I believe the one I found is helpful for the PTB (python-telegram-bot) users and community, so sharing it here.

Without further ado let's jump into it.

---

Let me start with the proper task statement:

> The solution should provide the easiest way to implement the basic job persistence (file-based) that would allow to: (1) restart the bot preserving all the scheduled jobs among all the chats, (2) have a last job queue state persisted so in case bot crushes it would take this state once the problem is fixed.

To create a universal solution, we need to answer 3 questions:

1. How can we catch all job queue permutations, no matter what exact function schedules a new job or adjusts an existing one?
2. How to serialize whatever mess is inside of the job (no offense to PTB authors)?
3. How to recreate jobs if we don't know exactly how it was created in the first place (run_daily, run_monthly, etc)?

---

> 1. How can we catch all job queue permutations, no matter what exact function schedules a new job or adjusts an existing one?

Noticeably, PTB (python-telegram-bot) uses 3rd party solution for scheduling which is [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/). Thanks to the authors of that module, the listeners are conveniently [provided](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html#scheduler-events), so I just use them to catch the events I need: for adding and removing jobs.

The little part of the code:

```
def scheduler_event_catcher(event: JobEvent):
    logger.debug(f"Scheduler event: {event}, job id: {event.job_id}, "
            f"jobstore name: {event.jobstore}")
...
app = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()
app.job_queue.scheduler.add_listener(scheduler_event_catcher, 
    EVENT_JOB_REMOVED | EVENT_JOB_ADDED)
```

---

> 2. How to serialize whatever mess is inside of the job (no offense to PTB authors)?

If you take the job queue or job that you can reach from PTB (python-telegram-bot) and try to serialize it, you won't succeed. The main problem here is that among other data it includes pointers to callable functions. This is not something you can serialize straight ahead: the address where the callable is now may vary from what it will be the next time you start the bot.

Although the callable pointers serialization is covered poorly in the web as well, I will not go deeply into detail.
What is remarkable about APScheduler is that they are providing a solution to make scheduled jobs serializable. Many thanks to the authors once again!

Within apscheduler.util you can find *ref_to_obj* and *obj_to_ref* functions, that make it possible to have transitions object (callable) <-> string. There are limitations of course, but they are more than feasible: callable could be of types: functions, methods, classmethods, staticmethods.

Some pieces of code (it's not exactly accurate, but just to give you a clue):

```
def retrieve_state(job: Job):
    ...
    callback = obj_to_ref(job.callback)
    ...

def restore_state(job_queue: PTBJobQueue, serialized_job: dict):
    ...
    callback = ref_to_obj(serialized_job["callback"])
    ...
```

---

> 3. How to recreate jobs if we don't know exactly how it was created in the first place (run_daily, run_monthly, etc)?

That was a tricky one.
The thing is that APScheduler has Job class, and PTB has its own Job class on top of the original one.
Since APScheduler is actually providing the tools for persistence, their Job class provides means to save state and restore it (by *"_ _ getstate _ _"* and *"_ _ setstate _ _"*).
PTB Job class has nothing like that but is sticking to the original Job class. The clue was in the [PTB source code](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/ext/_jobqueue.py#L221), so this time thanks PTB authors for maintaining quite detailed docstrings. Once I discovered PTB Job and APScheduler Job relations, I was able to reproduce them and make the recreation of scheduled jobs which you can get familiar with in that [module](https://github.com/dikirilov/ptb-job-persistence-stackoverflow/blob/main/job_serialization.py).

Hope that will help each bot builder who will face the issue.

---